# What are the list of Resharper like plugins for VS I should consider?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My license for Whole Tomatoes Visual AssistX is about to expire and I'm not really planning on renewing it.  I use it for spell checking but that's about it.  The refactoring abilities have been a little disappointing.  Before I just jump into Resharper though what are your thoughts on other possible plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other major player would be DevExpress and their CodeRush and Refactor products. [Found here.](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from trying out Visual AssistX, the only other one I've tried is ReSharper (which I highly recommend). If you do decide to go for ReSharper, you'll likely notice that it's missing a spell checker for code though - however the [Agent Smith plugin](http://www.agentsmithplugin.com/) fixes that.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [Visual Studio Gallery](http://www.visualstudiogallery.com/), the *one stop shop for Visual Studio extensions*.

Here you'll find quite a lot of extensions for Visual Studio in all categories, from intellisense and refactoring to designers and documentation builders.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get into resharper, you really don't want to leave, its done a massive amount to improve my productivity.

It depends though on what you are doing. Are you doing a lot of TDD when you write tests, write code, then refactor?

Unless you are pretty intensely into refactoring then I'd suggest that you might not get the best of out R#.

As a plugin for a plugin I use the RGreatX plugin for R#. It's really handy for shifting string values out to resource files for localization of the software.....saves me plenty of time!

Answer (score 1):

[MZ-Tools](http://mztools.com/index.aspx) is really good as well.

Comment: But where's the refactoring support?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried model [maker code explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer-vs/index.html)?

It is a great tool in delphi and the visual studio version looks pretty sweet as well. Still trying to work out what the best option for VS is though.